# NodeJs - How to open new command prompt and run npm install command on newly open command prompt using nodejs script

Tags: node.js

Perform below task through NodeJS script

1. Open new command prompt
2. Change directory in new command prompt
3. Run "npm install" and "npm run start" command
4. Close parent command prompt (which was open to run node script) after new command prompt open in step 1.

Code:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec("start cmd.exe /K cd dirname");
```